# Finding something that checks if a particular Arithmetic answer is correct

Tags: python, function, if-statement, while-loop, eval

I am wondering if there is a command which can work out a mathematics question that you have asked and compare it to the answer the user has written? Obviously if it's wrong it will output wrong, and right if it's right. Here is my code:

```
import time
person=input('Hello there, what is your name? ')
print('Hello',person,'today you will test a maths quiz which is 10 questions')
time.sleep(1)
print('Good luck here is your first question:')
UserScore=0
UserWrong=0
x=0
while x<10:
    import random
    Ran=random.randint(1, 10) 
    dom=random.randint(1, 10)
    Operators=[ 'plus', 'minus', 'times']
    op = random.choice(Operators)
    AnswerOne=input('What is '+str(Ran) +' '+str(op) +' '+str(dom) +'? ')
    if int(AnswerOne) == Ran + dom:
        print('Correct!')
        UserScore= UserScore + 1
    elif int(AnswerOne) == Ran - dom:
        print('Correct!')
        UserScore= UserScore + 1
    elif int(AnswerOne) == Ran * dom:
        print('Correct!')
       UserScore= UserScore + 1
    else:
        print('You are wrong! Better look next time :D')
        UserWrong= UserWrong +1
    x=x+1
print('You got '+str(UserScore) +' right and '+str(UserWrong) +' wrong')
```

Comment: Try the [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#eval) function. This might be what you're looking for.

Comment: In my other question i mentioned the eval function but i did not know what it was :/ excatly

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Edit:**  Ok, I sliced this down a bit more.

I have a Question base class and four subclasses: Multiplication, Division, Addition, and Subtraction.

Each time you create a Question object, it initializes itself with random values. You can then request a question string and the related answer value.

```
from random import choice, randint

class Question:     # base class
    def __init__(self, difficulty=20):
        self.a = randint(1, difficulty)
        self.b = randint(1, difficulty)
    def question(self):
        raise NotImplemented
    def answer(self):
        raise NotImplemented

class Multiplication(Question):
    def question(self):
        return "What is {} * {}? ".format(self.a, self.b)
    def answer(self):
        return self.a * self.b

class Division(Question):
    def question(self):
        # invert the question to ensure a nice answer value
        return "What is {} / {}? ".format(self.a * self.b, self.a)
    def answer(self):
        return self.b

class Addition(Question):
    def question(self):
        return "What is {} + {}? ".format(self.a, self.b)
    def answer(self):
        return self.a + self.b

class Subtraction(Question):
    def question(self):
        # invert the question to ensure a nice answer value
        return "What is {} - {}? ".format(self.a + self.b, self.a)
    def answer(self):
        return self.b
```

I then use the classes to implement a function which asks a question and marks the result,

```
def do_question(qtypes=[Multiplication, Division, Addition, Subtraction]):
    # pick a random question-type
    #   and create a question of that type
    q = choice(qtypes)()
    # prompt user for their answer
    guess = get_int(q.question())
    # mark their answer
    if guess == q.answer():
        print("Correct!")
        return True
    else:
        print("Sorry, the right answer was {}".format(q.answer()))
        return False
```

and a function which asks a set number of questions and returns the total score,

```
def do_quiz(num_questions=10):
    return sum(do_question() for i in range(1, num_questions + 1))
```

then we give a quiz and show the result:

```
def main():
    correct = do_quiz()
    print("\nYou solved {} of 10 questions".format(correct))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and, when run, this looks like

```
What is 8 * 2? 16
Correct!

What is 1 + 3? 4
Correct!

What is 27 - 12? 15
Correct!

What is 17 + 1? 19
Sorry, the right answer was 18

What is 4 / 1? 4
Correct!

What is 19 - 14? 5
Correct!

What is 36 / 3? 12
Correct!

What is 12 * 7? 84
Correct!

What is 48 / 4? 12
Correct!

What is 26 - 8? 18
Correct!

You solved 9 of 10 questions
```

Comment: What is this may i ask?

Comment: I've seen five or six people asking the same question; I presume it's homework for CS 201 or something similar. For fun, I wrote up a nice class-based version; you create (for example) a Multiplication problem and it gives the text of the question and the value answer. There was a bunch of other stuff - a menu system, save and display results - which I stripped back out to simplify things.

Comment: Oh nice ^_^  That looks pretty complex xD

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is workable, you just need to adjust the conditions slightly. You're currently saying "if the user's answer is a+b, then its right" - even if the question was "what is a times b". So, you need to also check that the operation matches. You could do something like this:

```
if answer == ran+dom and op == 'plus':
     # correct
```

And similarly for the other operations.

You could also simplify it a lot by using a dictionary instead of a list for your operations - the keys would be the current strings, and the values a function that does the right operation, such as the ones in the operator module, so:

```
operations = { "plus": operator.add, 
               "times": operator.mul,
               "minus": operator.sub
             }
```

This lets you simplify down to *one* condition - you can pull the appropriate checking function out of the dictionary and test if it gives the same answer as the user:

```
if operations[op](ran, dom) == answer:
    # correct
```

This covers all three branches, and any more you decide to add later.

Comment: Thanks you greatly! I will try to use the dictionaries but first i am going to learn more about them but for now i will use the top one